# Cucumber Scenario: Should be listed in chronological order by date in ASC order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Scenario: Events should be listed in chronological order by event date in ASC order

How do i test this scenario in cucumber? 
Events has a name and a event_date. Events is shown in a list in the GUI. I want the test to fail when the events is in a unsorted order and the test to pass when the list is sorted by event_date ASC order.

The real problem is how to define the following step

Then /^I should see a list that has the first element "([^\"]*)"$/ do |element|
 ???????????????????????????????????????????????

end

Comment: What are you using to drive your UI interactions within Cucumber?  Is it Capybara, Webrat, something else?

Answer (score 0):

create your event with like title the current date. Separate by one day. After you can check if the first element is the older event or youngest.

Comment: Then /^I should see a list that has the first element "([^\"]*)"$/ do |element|
????????? 
end

Comment: here is real problem. How to define the step for this comparison